# Where can I find the default display settings for each monitor?

Tags: dell, hdmi, display-resolution, vga

Using Ubuntu 18.04 with two very old Dell monitors.

I recently had to update my motherboard and consequently had to add an Accell j129b-003b adapter to convert HDMI to VGA.

Alright...I know that the default display settings for each user is stored in ~/.config/monitors.xml.  However, if a specific user has not ever logged in, they get a message on the screen (which I believe comes from the monitor itself), as you can see below:

[image: Cannot Display This Video Mode]

So, not to worry, I have the user change the display settings for that monitor to the 1280x1024 setting, and all is well.  However...if I reboot the machine, or if that user logs out, the login screen (with all users shown) displays the same message, before even logging in.  So, I'm thinking that root has a location where it's display settings are stored, and what I would like to do is update those so that the root settings default to 1280x1024, as opposed to something else, which forces this message to come up.

Where does root keep the default screen resolution settings?

Thank you!

Update:

Running xrandr provides the following:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2560 x 1024, maximum 8192 x 8192
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 connected primary 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 256mm x 192mm
   1920x1200     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     60.02* 
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
DP-1 connected 1280x1024+1280+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 338mm x 270mm
   1280x1024     60.02*+  75.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

Comment: Have you tried running `xrandr` from the command line yet?

Comment: Just ran and updated...see above.

Comment: If I understand correctly a new user's HDMI-2 defaults to 1920x1080, your VGA monitor complains and you have to change it to 1280x1024 one time?

Comment: That is correct.  Each user has to change it only one time.  However, the annoying issue that I am trying to solve is that when any user logs out or when any user reboots the machine, the issue comes back and lays over the login screen.  This makes sense since technically, no users are logged in and thus no users' resolution settings should be touched.  So, how do I change the root resolution?

Comment: Do you create a default user account and then copy that for each new user so you don't have to repeat file permissions and directory names? If so default monitor configuration could be in the bash copy script.

Comment: My user's profiles are created from /etc/skel/, like normal, but I don't feel I need to add any more users.  In fact, the users' profiles are simply not a concern to me...I have that part solved.  What I am looking for is the default location for root's resolution settings.

Comment: You can try `head /var/log/Xorg.0.log -n50`. Look for something like this: `Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"` and this: `Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"`. Hopefully someone reads our conversation and posts a good answer. I'm on a single user system and copy things to root, never from root.

Comment: I don't have `/var/log/Xorg...` and I also don't have `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.  I do however have `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`

Comment: Pinging to see if anyone may have any other ideas...I still do not have a solution.